# Different console font sizes on two installations of debian wheezy

Tags: debian, console, fonts, debian-installer

I have installed Debian Wheezy on two different partitions of the same desktop computer.

The first installation was done a few months ago with a version 7.5 iso image. The installation has been upgraded on a regular basis using `apt-get`.

The second was done one week ago with a 7.8 iso image. The installer detected the previous debian installation and set up grub to see both installations. Now I can boot into any of the two debian instances.

When using the older instance, the console boots with a relatively large font and after a few seconds switches to a smaller font.

When using the newer instance, the console boots with a large font and does not switch to the smaller one.

I would like to have the same behaviour on both installations, namely the smaller console fonts.

At first I thought it could be a grub problem but, since there is one grub managing all the boot configurations, I suppose the problem is in the configuration of Debian itself.
Next thing I looked at both `/etc/default/console-setup` but they are identical on the two systems.

So, why do the two systems use different console font sizes? Has the default changed between Wheezy 7.5 and 7.8? Or can it depend on packages that have been installed on one system but not on the other?

In any case, how can I find the font size used by the older system and set it on the new system?

**EDIT**

I just did a fresh install of Debian 8 on a free partition and I have the same problem: the fonts in the console mode are pretty large and stay like that. In previous installations of Debian 7 on many different machines (even a 12 year old laptop), the console starts with large fonts at boot, but then switches to smaller fonts before starting the X server. After that, when I switch to a console with ALT-F1-6, I get a console with small fonts.

In my current Debian 8 installation, on a new desktop, console fonts remain large.

Comment: Do you have X configured on either/both instances?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: Yes. I suppose X was chosen automatically when installing the gnome desktop.

Comment: It can be that I chose `desktop` in the installer only for one instance but I am not sure any more. Does gnome get installed on a non-desktop installation (that would be the older one)?

Comment: Well, look at the X config file, which would be at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` if it exists.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: Are the text consoles also controlled by the X server? Anyway, I don't have this file on either system.

Comment: These are the virtual consoles that are obtained with Alt-Fi, for i=1,...6, right?  If so, I don't think the X server controls it.

Comment: Yes, I mean the virtual consoles, and also the console that appears during boot. I am not sure if that is a virtual console already: as far as I understand, at least part of the boot logging is shown before the virtual consoles are started.

Comment: I suggest hopping in the main chat room. This is probably best done interactively. While I don't have much idea about this, there are other people who might. You can ping me there if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem, which occurred on new installations of both Debian 7 and Debian 8. The problem was that the kernel did not switch the graphic mode during boot. I noticed some error messages in the log complaining that `firmware-linux-nonfree` was missing.

Doing

```
$ sudo apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree
```

solved the problem.